# Build Vue application to support Server Side Rendering on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am building a Vue Application with Nuxt. I have built with SSR mode. It builds server-side build with entry point .Nuxt/server.js.

I am using https://ssr.vuejs.org/api/#createbundlerenderer to create renderer on NodeJS, so I can provide template Html with the component inside and it will be able to render that component. But the problem is server.js is using **import** statements to import modules which is not working with NodeJS.

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { stringify } from '...'
                                                          ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I tried to set `"type": "module"` in the package.json or use the .mjs extension. But, had no luck with that.

Here is the generated server build.

```
import { stringify } from 'querystring'
import Vue from 'vue'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import middleware from './middleware.js'
...
```

Here is the code I have used to render above generated build.

```
const { createBundleRenderer } = require('vue-server-renderer');

const renderer = createBundleRenderer('/ABSOLUTE_PATH/.nuxt/server.js');
renderer.renderToString().then(html => console.log(html)).catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Can anyone please help me to generate Node-style server bundle?

Comment: could you show us where you import it?

Comment: @ifaruki I have updated the question. Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ifaruki if you have experience with server-side rendering using another way like using webpack then also please let me know. I would like to try that.

Comment: did you tried using `require()` instead?

Comment: Yeah I tried manually changing from import to require() but then it is not able to find user-defined modules like middleware.js though it does exist

Comment: did you tried dynamic import?

Comment: Yeah, I tried but no luck there.

Comment: could you show me how you tried it with dynamic import?

Comment: import('./middleware.js').then(m => middleware = m).catch(e => console.error('Error', e))

Comment: Does this throw the same error or different?

Comment: It shows the same error

Comment: @vivekpatel why don't you just use Nuxt? Or just have a look at how they solved this problem? https://nuxtjs.org/ That does SSR on Node out of the box.

Comment: @muka.gergely Thanks for the input. Sure, I will check.